# Prove closed form for $\sum_k (2k)^2\binom{2n}{k+n} $ and $\sum_ k(2k+1)^2\binom{2n+1}{k+n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk, binomial-theorem

The following identities,  are true, but I am having trouble proving them:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\sum_k (2k)^2\binom{2n}{k+n} &=& (2n)2^{2n} \\ 
\sum_ k(2k+1)^2\binom{2n+1}{k+n+1} &=& (2n+1)2^{2n+1}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The sums in these identities range over all integer values of $k$, but for any given $n$ there are just a finite number of non-zero terms.
[The convention (following Knuth) is that a binomial coefficient with a negative lower index like $\binom{7}{1}$ or an lower endex exceeding the upper index like $\binom{8}{9}$ is zero.]

These identities can be used to show that the expectation of $x^2$ at epoch $t$ of a 1-dimensional discrete $p=\frac{1}{2}$ random walk along the X axis is $t$.

I have tried induction on $n$, but the algebra has gotten a bit hairy.  Is there a cleaner way?  And if not, can somebody demonstrate the induction step (the basis is easy for $n=1$)?

Comment: Although the sum is over all integer $k$, in the first case only values $-n \leq k \leq n$ matter since the binomial coefficients are zero outside that range.  So it is $\sum_{k=-n}^{n}$. In the odd case, the range for non-zero terms is  $\sum_{k=-1-n}^{n}$.

Comment: Observe that the sum $$\sum_{k=-n}^n (2k)^2 {2n\choose n+k}\quad\text{turns into}\quad 4 \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (k^2-2kn+n^2) {2n\choose  k}$$ which has three very simple pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These can both be proven using the binomial identity
$$
\binom{a}{b}\binom{b}{c}=\binom{a}{c}\binom{a-c}{b-c}\tag{1}
$$
For the first
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-n}^n(2k)^2\binom{2n}{k+n}
&=4\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(k-n)^2\binom{2n}{k}\\
&=4\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left[2\binom{k}{2}-(2n-1)\binom{k}{1}+n^2\right]\binom{2n}{k}\\
&=4\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left[2\binom{2n-2}{k-2}\binom{2n}{2}-(2n-1)\binom{2n-1}{k-1}\binom{2n}{1}+n^2\binom{2n}{k}\right]\\[6pt]
&=4\left[2n(2n-1)2^{2n-2}-2n(2n-1)2^{2n-1}+n^22^{2n}\right]\\[12pt]
&=4\left[-n(2n-1)2^{2n-1}+2n^22^{2n-1}\right]\\[12pt]
&=2n2^{2n}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

---

For the second
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-n}^n(2k+1)^2\binom{2n+1}{k+n+1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(2k-2n+1)^2\binom{2n+1}{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left[8\binom{k+1}{2}-8n\binom{k+1}{1}+(2n+1)^2\right]\binom{2n+1}{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left[8\binom{2n+1}{2}\binom{2n-1}{k-1}-8n\binom{2n+1}{1}\binom{2n}{k}+(2n+1)^2\binom{2n+1}{k+1}\right]\\[6pt]
&=\left[8n(2n+1)2^{2n-1}-8n(2n+1)2^{2n}+(2n+1)^22^{2n+1}\right]\\[12pt]
&=\left[-8n(2n+1)2^{2n-1}+4(2n+1)^22^{2n-1}\right]\\[12pt]
&=(2n+1)2^{2n+1}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We may consider that:

$$ \sum_{k=-n}^{n}\binom{2n}{n+k} z^k = \frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^n} \tag{1}$$
then replace $z$ with $e^{i\theta}$ and take the real part:
$$ -\binom{2n}{n}+2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{n+k} \cos(k\theta) = \left(2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^n\tag{2}$$
differentiate twice with respect to $\theta$ then consider $\theta\to 0$.

The odd case is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Just shift $k$ to $k-n$, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-n}^n (2k)^2 \binom{2n}{n+k}&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(2(k-n))^2\binom{2n}{k}\\
&=4\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2n}n^2\binom{2n}{k} -\sum_{k=0}^{2n}2nk\binom{2n}{k}+ \sum_{k=0}^{2n}k^2\binom{2n}{k}\right)\\
&=4(n^2 2^{2n}-2n\cdot 2n 2^{2n-1}+2n\cdot 2^{2n-1}+2n(2n-1)2^{2n-2})\\
&=(4n^2-8n^2+4n+4n^2-2n)2^{2n}\\
&=2n\cdot 2^{2n}.
\end{align}
Using similar method, you can also verify second identity:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-n-1}^n (2k+1)^2 \binom{2n+1}{k+n+1}&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}(2k-2n-1)^2\binom{2n+1}{k}\\
&=(2n+1)2^{2n+1}.
\end{align}